# Is it better to use self variable than pass variable in a class?

Tags: python

I used to be a c programmer, so we have to pass every variable as argument or pointer and not encouraged to define global variable.

I am going to use some variable in several functions in python.

Generally, which is better, pass the variable as an argument, or define a self variable when we get the value of the variables? Does python has any general rules about this?

Like this:

```
class A:
    def func2(self, var):
        print var

    def func1(self):
        var = 1
        self.func2(var)

class B:
    def func2(self):
        print self.var

    def func1(self):
        self.var = 1
        self.func2()
```

Which is better? A or B?

Comment: If you are going to use global constants like black = (0,0,0) then you don't need to create  a self variable otherwise you usually should

Comment: What do you mean by "define a self argument"?

Comment: I think Class B func1 needs to set self.var=1 not var=1, right?

Comment: The general rule is: If a property is part of an object’s state, then it should be an instance variable. It depends on the semantics of the object. Does `var` belong to the object of type `A`/`B`? Then yes, make it an instance variable.

Comment: Btw. I’m voting to close this question as “too broad”. While you may think it’s specific to Python, this is really just about general OOP design. As you learn about object oriented design in general, you will learn when to use instance variables and when you don’t; or what kind of members belong to an object, and which don’t but should be placed elsewhere. Just look at general OOP resources.

Comment: This might be a OOP problem. I haven't done a lot of OO programming, but AFAIK, python is the only language that can so easily make new variables(attributes) dynamically for an instance. So, this is especially a problem for python I think.

Comment: Any dynamically typed OO language can do that. And that doesn’t inpact the decision whether a property should be an instance variable or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, you have a lot of freedom to do what "makes sense". In this case, I would say that it depends on how you plan on using `func2` and who will be accessing it. If `func2` is only ever supposed to act upon `self.var`, then you should code it as such. If other objects are going to need to pass in different arguments to `func2`, then you should allow for it to be an argument. Of course, this all depends on the larger scope of *what you're trying to do*, but given your simple example, this makes sense.

Also, I'm confused about how your question relates to *global variables*. Member variables are not the same thing as global variables.

Edited to reflect updated post:

The difference between A and B in your example is that B persists the information about `self.var`, while A does not. If `var` needs to be persisted as part of the object's state, then you need to store it as part of `self`. I get the sense that your question might relate more to objects as a general concept than anything Python-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's better to design your program to use scope intelligently. The most obvious problem is that a mutation of a global variable can affect distant parts of code in ways that are difficult to trace, but in addition, garbage collection (reference counting, whatever) becomes effectively moot when your references live in long-lived scopes.

That said, Python has a `global` keyword, but it doesn't have globals in the same way `c` does. Python globals are module level, so they're namespaced with the module by default. The downstream programmer can bypass or alias this namespacing, but that's his/her problem. There are certainly cases where defining a module-level configuration value, pseudo-enum or -const makes sense.

Next, consider whether you need to maintain state: if the behavior of an object depends on it being aware of a certain value, make it a property. You can do that by attaching the value to `self`. Otherwise, just pass the value as an argument. (But then, if you have a lot of methods and *no* state, ask yourself if you really need a class, or should they just be module functions?)

Answer (score 1):

This questions has implications towards object-oriented design. **Python is an object oriented language; c is not**. You would be dramatically undermining (and in some cases thwarting) object oriented advantages to use in-out programming or entirely global variables in Python except where there's particular reason to do so.

Consider the following reasons, which are not exhaustive:

- Garbage collection won't know when to collect if the variables are all global
- You no longer have fields (which is what "self" helps you reference). Say your object is a Cat; there isn't some global name for a cat which you reassign whenever a new Cat appears in your neighborhood. Rather, each cat has its own name, age, size, etc. Someone who wants to find out how big the cat is shouldn't have to go to some global repository of cat sizes and look it up, they should just look at the cat
- You can run into problems with primitives because Python, unlike C, does not let you track (easily) the reference of an object. If I pass in an integer variable, I can't change the value of the variable in its original location, only within the scope of the function. This can be solved with global variables, but only by being very messy. Consider the following code:

  ```
  def foo(x):
         x = 3
  myVar = 5
  foo(myVar)
  print(myVar)
  ```

This will, of course, output 5, not three. There is no "`x*`" like there is in C, so solving this would be rather tricky in Python if we wanted foo to reassign 3 to the input variable. Rather, we could write

```
     class Foo:
          x = 5

     def foo( fooObj ):
         fooObj.x = 3

     myFoo = Foo()
     foo(myFoo)
     print(myFoo.x)
```

Problem solved - it now outputs 3, not 5!

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, it is better to use `self` whenever possible, to encapsulate internal information and bind it to object (or class). I may be helpful to explain how `self` and classes work.

In Python class or object variables are passed to methods explicitly, just as you would do in C if you want to do OOP. This is different from other object oriented languages, like Java or C++, where this argument is passed implicitly (but it always is!).
Thus if you define class like:

```
Class B(object):
    def __init__(self, var=None): # this is constructor
        self.var = var

    def func2(self):
        print self.var
```

when you call object method with `.` operator, this object will be passed as the first argument, that maps to `self` in method signature:

```
b = B(1)  # object b is created and B.__init__(b, 1) is called
b.func2() # B.func2(b) is called, outputs 1
```

I hope this clears up things for you a bit

Answer (score 0):

I recommend focusing on proximity.  If the variable only relates to the current method or is created to be passed to another method, then it probably isn't expressing the persistent state of the class instance.  Create the variable and throw it away when you're done.

If the variable describes an important facet of the instance, use `self`.  This is not encroaching on your aversion to global variables as the variable is encapsulated within the instance.  Class and module variables are also fine for the same reason.

In short, both A and B are proper implementations depending on context.  I'm sorry that I haven't given you a clear answer but it has more to do with how important an object is to the objects around it than maintaining any sort of community standard.  That you asked the question makes me think you'll make a reasonable judgement.

Comment: @dspjm I'm learning C after working in Python.  It's fun to see how different environments force us to question our habits.